# AJAX returns whole web page after 2nd form submit - JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My code works as expected the first time the form submits. I'm forcing an error by entering wrong credentials, it shows an error, all fine. After doing so it should log me in if I enter the correct credentials the second time the form submits. The problem is, `data` in my AJAX call contains the whole web page instead of a JSON string after submitting for the second time.

**I'm using the following code (JS):**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        var $u = $('#rnumber').val(),
            $p = $('#password').val(),
            $t = $('#token').val(),
            $s = $('#source').val(),
            $key = false;

        var $r = $('#remember:checked').length > 0;

        if(!$u) {
            // Add Error
            $('#alert_error').show();
            $('#login_error').text('Relatienummer is verplicht!');
            $key = true;
            $('#input_rnumber').addClass('has-error');

            // Check if input has been filled
            $( "#rnumber" ).keyup(function() {
                $('#input_rnumber').removeClass('has-error');
                $('#alert_error').hide();
                $key = false;
            });
        } else if(!$p) {
            $('#alert_error').show();
            $('#login_error').text('Wachtwoord is verplicht!');
            $key = true;
            $('#input_pass').addClass('has-error');

            // Check if input has been filled
            $( "#password" ).keyup(function() {
                $('#input_pass').removeClass('has-error');
                $('#alert_error').hide();
                $key = false;
            });
        }

        if(!$s) {
            $s = null;
        }

        event.preventDefault(event);

        if($key == false) {
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '/cp/login.php',
                data: {u: $u, p: $p, t: $t, r: $r, s: $s},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data) {

                    console.log(data);

                    data = data.substring(data.indexOf("{"));

                    var json = JSON.parse(data);

                    console.log(json);

                    if(json.Error == 'Login') {
                        $('#alert_error').show();
                        $('#login_error').text(json.Message);

                        $('#password').val("");

                        // Check if input has been filled
                        $( "#password" ).keyup(function() {
                            $('#alert_error').hide();
                        });
                    } else if(json.Error == 'Membership') {
                        $('#alert_error').show();
                        $('#login_error').html(json.Message);

                        $('#password').val("");
                    } else if(json.Redirect) {
                        $('#loading').show();

                        var counter = 5;
                        var interval = setInterval(function() {
                            counter--;

                            $('#loading_text').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i> Je word doorgestuurd in ' + counter + ' seconden.');

                            if (counter == 5) {
                                clearInterval(interval);
                            }
                        }, 1000);

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.replace("http://" + document.location.hostname + "/" + json.Redirect);
                        }, 5000);
                    } else if(json.Success == 'Dashboard') {
                        $('#loading').show();
                        $('#loading_text').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i> Je word ingelogd...');

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.replace("dashboard");
                        }, 2000);
                    } else if(json.Success == 'Admin') {
                        $('#loading').show();
                        $('#loading_text').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i> Je word ingelogd...');

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.replace("http://" + document.location.hostname + '/admin/');
                        }, 2000);
                    } else if(json.Success == 'Company') {
                        $('#loading').show();
                        $('#loading_text').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i> Je word ingelogd...');

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.replace("http://" + document.location.hostname + '/company/dashboard');
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Login.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['u']) && isset($_POST['p']) && isset($_POST['t']) && isset($_POST['r'])) {

    if(Token::check(escape($_POST['t']))) {

        $rnumber = escape($_POST['u']);
        $pass = escape($_POST['p']);
        $remember = escape($_POST['r']);
        $source = escape($_POST['s']);

        if(substr( $rnumber, 0, 1 ) === "c") {

            $c = new Company();

            $cInfo = $c->findR($rnumber);
            $cInfo = $c->data();

            $login = $c->login($rnumber, $pass, $remember);

            if($login) {
                print json_encode(array("Success"=>"Company"));
                exit();
            } else {
                print json_encode(array("Error"=>"Login", "Message"=>"Er zijn onjuiste inloggegevens ingevoerd! Probeer het opnieuw!"));
                exit();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE:

I changed my first `if()` statement in the success function from AJAX. It currently looks like this:

```
if(json.Error == 'Login') {

    $('#alert_error').show();
    $('#login_error').text(json.Message);

    $('#password').val("");

    console.log('returning false');

    return false;
}
```

After I enter invalid credentials and submit the form for the first time, it shows the error message as expected. It also logs `returning false`.

When I try entering the correct credentials and submit the form for the second time, it won't do anything.

I also added `dataType: 'json'` to the AJAX call.

So after putting `console.log()` at some places in my code, I noticed that when I submit the form for the second time, it does submit the form, and it is firing a AJAX request. It just does not return a new JSON string from PHP.

Comment: It did not say `"Success"=>"Company"`?

Comment: @StephanSutter Nope, just returns the whole web page

Comment: What is the result of this `console.log(json);`? Did you try `console.log(json.Error);`?

Comment: @StephanSutter As excepted, `console.log(json);` results in `VM9141:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: how about `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @StephanSutter `console.log(data);` results in the whole web page being shown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117552/discussion-between-stephan-sutter-and-chris).

Comment: If you look at the data for the returned webpage, does it come from this PHP class, or perhaps something else?

Comment: It comes from the login page, which is the current web page (the one where the JS file is included)

Comment: Oh, and you should always perform all validation on the server, not just the client. Never trust the data coming from the client. BTW, I noticed you don't use a framework for routing.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't go into the first if condition? To investigate I would debug the path taken through the code. Or add some logging in the PHP class to see where it goes.

Comment: It does go into the first condition. Everything else is working as expected

Comment: Updated the post with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get everything working again.

I noticed that the `token` in my form did not change. This is of course because the page does not refresh.

So, I created a simple javascript function that fires a AJAX request to another PHP file that will change the token to a new valid one.

```
function token() {

    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/cp/_token.php',
        data: {token: true},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            $('#token').val(output);
        }
    });

}

if(json.Error == 'Login') {

    $('#alert_error').show();
    $('#login_error').text(json.Message);

    $('#password').val("");

    token();

    // Check if input has been filled
    $( "#password" ).keyup(function() {
      $('#alert_error').hide();
      return false;
    });
}
```

Thanks everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Please make few changes in your code.

1. Remove keyup event from submit function and placed it outside.
2. When there is an error during form submission like validation error then return false(It break the execution process).

Comment: Why do I have to place the `keyup` event outside of my `submit` function?

Comment: When there is an error occurred during validation process then you have to return false to break the current execution. And when you break the execution of the function then your key up event is not working any more.

Comment: When you get any error simply show the error message and add your error class and then break the execution. So when you submit  form again with correct data it start execution from scratch.

Comment: Alright, so I just added the `return false;` after I show the error message. It still gives the same result. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Add dataType: 'json' in ajax.

Comment: I tried that before, but I doesn't work. I think it won't work because there is more than just JSON in the `data`. That's why I used `data = data.substring(data.indexOf("{"));` to filter out the JSON

Comment: When you add dataType: 'json' then there is no need to parse the json. simply check data.Error

Comment: Just added the `dataType: 'json'`. The second time I try to submit the form nothing happens